# Spring JPA to get list based on list

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I have the following documents in mongo collection

```json
{
    "_id": "623d3b001a7d266bf1aa5",
    "uniqueId": "abc",
    "count": 25
},
{
    "_id": "623d3b001a7d266bf1aa6",
    "uniqueId": "bcd",
    "count": 25
},
{
    "_id": "623d3b001a7d266bf1aa7",
    "uniqueId": "efg",
    "count": 108
}
```

In the request, I will get uniqueIdList like **[“abc”,”bcd”]** to get the list of documents

Currently am calling for each unique id and forming the list

```
Flux.fromIterable(request.getUniqueIds())
    .flatMap(uniqueId -> repo.findByUniqueId(uniqueId))
    .collectList()
    .map(util::transformResponse);
```

Response look like:

```json
[
    {"uniqueId": "abc","count": 25},
    {"uniqueId": "bcd","count": 25}
]
```

Friends, the question is

Do we have Spring Mongo JPA to fetch the list of values using list of unique keys rather than calling for each id?

like below

```
Flux<MyObject> get(List<String> uniqueIds)
```

Comment: In native query, you use `db.collection.find( { uniqueId: { $in: [ "abc", "bcd", "zzz" ] } })` to get for matching uniqueIds. `$in` translates to - { uniqueId: "abc" } or { uniqueId: "bcd" } or { uniqueId: "zzz" }.

Comment: Awsome Prasad bro. Thanks much. Yes we can do with @Query("{'productId':{ $in: ?0 }}")
  Flux<MyObject> get(List<String> uniqueIds)